# putchar() not returning value?

Tags: c

I am using the book 'The C Programming Language' to learn C.

I copied code exactly but the `putchar()` won't return the value of what the user types in.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

If I input this

`c`

I don't get any output

Comment: example input outputs?

Comment: `char c;` --> `int c;`

Comment: Those give me the same output.

Comment: Add a `flush(stdout)` after the `putchar()` call.

Comment: You might be seeing the effects of buffering, both in the input and output.  The program may not see any input at all until you enter a carriage return.  And any output may also be buffered until the program outputs a carriage return (or calls `fflush(stdout)`).  The details will depend on your operating system and possibly your terminal settings.

Comment: Also on the 1st iteration `c` is used uninitialised. Change `int c:` to be `int c = '<some printable character>';`

Comment: Did you press `Enter` after typing a character?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: @alk  buffering (otherwise you might as well call write directly)

Comment: I'm new to C and I only know Python. Could you please explain?

Comment: @PSkocik: The OP wonders why nothing is printed. This is because of `stdout` is line-buffered by default. The flushing works around it. What's the issue?

Comment: @JordanBaron `stdout` will not be printed without the new line (`\n`) character. This is a way to tell the program to print without that character.

Comment: It *might* be printed without a `newline`: it is with MSVC (perhaps because an input is requested), but `fflush(stdout)` ensures it.

Comment: @alk The `fflush` call won't change a thing for a program connected to a terminal in cooked mode.

Comment: @PSkocik: `flush()`ing `stdout` makes the C program spit out what had been `putchar()`/`printf()`ed into `stdout`'s output buffer to whichever output device is connected.

Comment: @alk Terminals in canonical mode only send input to the foreground program when a newline is encountered. The same newline that triggered the input will already be there to trigger an implicit fflush. If he wants a fully interactive experience he needs to switch the terminal to raw mode, and preferably disable output buffering for the whole stream instead of calling fflush after each outputted character.

Comment: @PSkocik: I am, just talking about flushing ***out***put.

Comment: @PSkocik This is a solution to the OP's question. Your answer below does not work for the OP so please come up with a solution that works and I will be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: @PSkocik: `fflush`ìng does not work for the OP? Really? Where doe s/he tell this?

Comment: @duncan Interesting. I get absolutely the same behavior with or without fflush.

Comment: @PSkocik it is unlikely that the OP is using a terminal if *"using the book 'The C Programming Language' to learn C."* You have introduced a red herring, if cooked (even smoked), that's a "kipper".

Comment: @PSkocik: It probably boils down to the OP ***not*** hitting the enter-key after inputting a character ... *sigh*

Comment: @PSkocik Note that `stdio` is not specified by C to flush its output when encountering a `'\n'`.  Yet [@alk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617828/putchar-not-returning-value#comment68470735_40617926) is likely correct about OP's main issue as you are concerning OP's expectations.